# Problem with 3D wireframe visualization in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I need to plot 3D data of the form z_i as function of (x_i, y_i) using a wireframe. I wrote the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import scipy.interpolate as spint

## Data to plot
sim_data = np.array([[ 20,   1,   8],
   [ 20,   2,   7],
   [ 20,   4,   7],
   [ 20,   6,   6],
   [ 20,  10,   6],
   [ 50,   0.4,  15],
   [ 50,   0.8,  11],
   [ 50,   1,  10],
   [ 50,   2,   8],
   [ 50,   4,   7],
   [ 50,   6,   7],
   [ 50,  10,   7],
   [100,   0.4,  22],
   [100,   0.8,  15],
   [100,   1,  13],
   [100,   2,  10],
   [100,   4,   8],
   [100,   6,   7],
   [100,  10,   7]])

x = sim_data[:, 0]
y = sim_data[:, 1]
z = sim_data[:, 2]

# Do trisurf plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
ax.set_xlabel('Air flow')
ax.set_ylabel('Fuel rate')
ax.set_zlabel('Temp.')
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.95, "Trisurf plot", transform=ax.transAxes)

# Transform from vector to grid
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
xi   = (X, Y)

Z    = spint.griddata((x,y), z, xi)

# Do wireframe plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('Air flow')
ax.set_ylabel('Fuel rate')
ax.set_zlabel('Temp.')
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.95, "Wireframe plot", transform=ax.transAxes)

# Do surface plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('Air flow')
ax.set_ylabel('Fuel rate')
ax.set_zlabel('Temp.')
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.95, "Surface plot", transform=ax.transAxes)
```

But I get some annoying extra wires (marked with a red arrow):

[image]

How can I get rid of this arrow? I have the same problem while trying a surface plot by the way:

[image]

My goal is to have a plot similar to a trisurf plot like the one below, but with a wireframe visualization.

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's wrong with wireframe?

I am not sure, but I think the problem is in your data. It's small and if you look carefully you will see that it looks like a stack of three different lines (observations). Look at this plot:

[image: img0]

it's definitely there are three parallel lines over there. I suppose, that's might cause confusion with `plot_wireframe`, as well as with `plot` from the previous image. I see 3 possible solutions:

### Solution 1: Use `plot`

Ok, so the first solution is not to use `plot_wireframe` at all. Let's use good old one `plot` to build our own wires. But first, let's break our data into 3 lines data:

```py
line1 = sim_data[0:5][::-1]  # NOTE: the first line is shorter
line2 = sim_data[5:12][::-1]
line3 = sim_data[12:][::-1]
```

Plot them all!

```py
# a helper function
def prepare_fig(fw=7, fh=7, view = (25, 30)):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fw, fh))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.view_init(view[0], view[-1])
    return ax

ax = prepare_fig()
ax.title.set_text('3 Lines')
for line in [line1, line2, line3]:
    x, y, z = line[:, 0], line[:, 1], line[:, 2]
    ax.plot(x, y, z, c='tab:blue', linewidth=3)
```

[image: img1]

Ok, we fixed undesired links, now let's add parallel links (lines) to connect our main lines:

```py
ax = prepare_fig()
ax.title.set_text('Paralel links')
for i in range(len(line3)):
    x, y, z = [], [], []
    if i < len(line1):
        x.append(line1[:, 0][i])
        y.append(line1[:, 1][i])
        z.append(line1[:, 2][i])
    else:
        # line1 is shorter so we will put nan here (for now)
        x.append(np.nan)
        y.append(np.nan)
        z.append(np.nan)
    x.extend([line2[:, 0][i], line3[:, 0][i]])
    y.extend([line2[:, 1][i], line3[:, 1][i]])
    z.extend([line2[:, 2][i], line3[:, 2][i]]) 
    ax.plot(x, y, z, c='tab:blue', linewidth=3)
```

[image: img2]

Now all in one:

**Final Code:**

```py
ax = prepare_fig()
ax.title.set_text('Handmade Wireframe (enclosed)')

line1 = sim_data[0:5][::-1]
line2 = sim_data[5:12][::-1]
line3 = sim_data[12:][::-1]

for line in [line1, line2, line3]:
    x, y, z = line[:, 0], line[:, 1], line[:, 2]
    ax.plot(x, y, z, c='tab:blue', linewidth=3)

for i in range(len(line3)):
    x, y, z = [], [], []
    if i < len(line1):
        x.append(line1[:, 0][i])
        y.append(line1[:, 1][i])
        z.append(line1[:, 2][i])
    else:
        # put nan because line1 is shorter
#         x.append(np.nan)
#         y.append(np.nan)
#         z.append(np.nan)
        # Or you can just replace it with last line1 value
        x.append(line1[:, 0][-1])
        y.append(line1[:, 1][-1])
        z.append(line1[:, 2][-1])
    x.extend([line2[:, 0][i], line3[:, 0][i]])
    y.extend([line2[:, 1][i], line3[:, 1][i]])
    z.extend([line2[:, 2][i], line3[:, 2][i]])
    ax.plot(x, y, z, c='tab:blue', linewidth=3)
```

[image: img3]

### Solution 2: Use `plot_trisurf`.

If triangles are acceptable, another solution is to transform trisurf to wireframe-like by some tweaking.

```py
x = sim_data[:, 0]
y = sim_data[:, 1]
z = sim_data[:, 2]

ax = prepare_fig()
ax.title.set_text('Trisurf Wireframe')

trisurf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
# turn of surface color, you can control it with alpha here:
trisurf.set_facecolor(mpl.colors.colorConverter.to_rgba('w', alpha=0.0))
# setting wire color
trisurf.set_edgecolor('tab:blue')
#setting wire width
trisurf.set_linewidth(3)
```

[image: img4]

### Solution 3: Use `plot_wireframe` and interpolation at linspace grid.

This might be solution if you want good looking smooth surface. You just need to generate new grid and then using `scipy`'s `spint.griddata` to perform interpolation:

```py
import scipy.interpolate as spint

x = sim_data[:, 0]
y = sim_data[:, 1]
z = sim_data[:, 2]

# generate new linear grid based on previous
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min(x), max(x), len(x)),
                   np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(y)))

Z = spint.griddata((x, y), z, (X, Y))

ax = prepare_fig()
ax.title.set_text('Interpotation on Linspace Grid')

# ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=3, cstride=3)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=3, cstride=3)
```

And you will get something like this:

[image: img5]